# Parallelizing Sieve of Eratosthenes Algorithm for finding Prime Number

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, algorithm

Parallelize Sieve of Eratosthenes method in two ways

1. using Java and
2. using C/C++ with Pthreads

Find the best values for THRESHOLD for 2 and 4 Core CPUs.

can any one help me how to do it. i am learning threads of java & C/C++.what things will i need to parallelize this algorithm

Comment: Is it homework? What did you try?

Comment: What have you done ? Did u read up some stuff ? Tried some samples ?

Comment: I think one of the main challenges is efficiently and concurrently marking the multiples of primes (or, hint, somehow avoiding concurrent access to the same location). For example, 3*5 is 5*3.

Comment: @PeterG.: I doubt it, since the serial algorithm iterates both 3*5 and 5*3 as well.

Comment: "Find the best values for THRESHOLD for 2 and 4 Core CPUs": what is this ???

Comment: @amit That is (part of) my point. For the serial algorithm the overlap does not matter. Concurrent access to the same locations will slow down things. When you look deeper (e.g. cache lines) the overlap is even bigger. A naive parallel implementation will have the threads compete for the same locations very often.

Answer (score 10):

Note that using the [Sieve of Eratostheens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) method to find the prime numbers table, once you find a prime number `i` - you set `i*n` as non-prime for each `n`.

Note that for 2 elements that you know they are prime numbers - `i,j` you can do it in parallel, `i` does not require any information from `j` and vise versa.

The same of course holds for each k prime numbers.

Note however that finding if a number is prime - depends on last calculations! Thus, a [barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_%28computer_science%29) is needed between marking numbers as non-primes and finding next prime number to work with.

A good place to start could be:

```
repeat until finished filling the table:
    1. Find k prime numbers [serially]
    2. Fill the table for these k numbers [parallely]
    3. after all threads finished step 2 [barrier] - return to 1
```

Since it seems homework, I'll only give these hints, and let you do the rest of the work. If you later have any specific problem - ask a new question and show us what you already did.

**EDIT**: one more important hint, note that if `i` is prime, the calculation of all the non prime numbers that derive from `i` will not affect the fact that `j` is prime for each `i < j < 2i`. Use this fact to find the `k` prime numbers, you don't want for example to take 2,3,4 as prime numbers on your first iteration of the algorithm.

Comment: The real problem is accessing the table.  You'll need some sort of synchronization so that two threads don't access the same word at the same time.

Comment: @JamesKanze There is no problem to access the table at the same time from two threads during the parallel step, since all table accesses are `table[i] = false`. There is no dependecy in this stage on the previous value of `table[i]` [or on `table[j]` for any `j`] and thus a synchronization is not needed here. [At the worst case you'll have two threads setting the same element to `false`, no data race in here]

Comment: @amt You're modifying an object from two different threads, which is undefined behavior unless there is synchronization.  Now, if you actually do something as silly as using one variable per entry, it's probable that the manifestation of the undefined behavior is that the code will work, but it's still undefined behavior (at least according to Posix and C++11).  And of course, in any real use, you'll be doing something like `sieve[i >> 3] |= 1 << (i & 7)`, which does have dependencies.

Answer (score 6):

Prime sieves use a lot of space.

In case of 1 bit per number, you'd need 1 giga-bit (2ˇ30) to store sieve for N = ~10ˇ9. And 1 terabit (2ˇ40) to store sieve for N = ~10ˇ12, which is 2ˇ37 bytes = 2ˇ7 GB = 128GB. 
If only storing odd numbers, 16 numbers/B, 64GB is needed for N=10ˇ9. With your laptops 16GB you'll be limited to N < 2ˇ35. Good to start cracking RSA 70-bit.
If making algorithm much more complex and not storing multiples of 3 5 or 7 in the seive, 1 byte would hold sieve-bits for 30 numbers, which would let ~2ˇ36 = 2ˇ(30+6) = ~64 x 10ˇ9, dangerous for RSA72 :lol: To crack RSA1024, youd need (1024/2 = 512,  512-36 = 476)
2ˇ476 (~10ˇ159) times more memory.

So memory usage is the main problem.

After all, even fast RAM is hundreds of times slower than CPU's L1 cache, so you want to fit the data to 32KB or upto 256KB instead of zillion TBs.

As the sieve is accessesd pretty randomly, it is not automagically loaded to cache and you'd get contineous cache-misses. You need to go through the range of numbers finishing the whole job chunk by chunk. While chunk-size is your fastest memory (L1 L2 of CPU or GPU).

Let's skip the complex part...

You'll have a list of primes that are needed to unmark composites in current junk. If already sieving big numbers, lets say 10ˇ30 upto 10ˇ30+10ˇ8, the range of 100M numbers has around 1M primes waiting in the list just to unmark 1 of their composites, each prime of that size would need (i guess) around 128B to be stored, so that you'd need 128MB for it. Luckyly this list is accessed sequentially and it may be already in cache when needed. But anyway you'll need zillion bytes to store the prime-lists for the next sieves.

About multithreading, scalability to GPUs, thousands of threads e.g.

Each prime in the list to unmark 1 bit in sieve in the fastest memory, accesses it basically randomly. GPu doesn't write bit by bit, instead it writes a la 128B per operation, it would be 1024bits. While 1 thread tries to unmark 1 bit, the other thread unmarks the otherbit while the bit of the 1st thread will have value 1 again. To fence/barrier/lock the memory would stop all the threads and no speed increase althoough lots of threads running.

So threads should not share the sieve. Would need to share sieving-prime-lists instead, so that each thread would have its own chunk of a chunk of sieve, and would use the same primes for unmarking. But after unmarking, they need to "schedule" that prime to the shared primes-list for its future sieve, which will be executed after millions of sievings, at the same time while other threads are changing the same list. Pretyy much stuck again.

It is very easy to make it parallel while slowing it down. Rather often it would be faster to recalculate something in each thread than to ask it over a slow bus like RAM, PCIe, SSD, GBit-net... but it is possible and not very complex if you have only some threads.

Comment: Please note you should press ENTER twice to create new paragraphs. I fixed it for you here :)

Answer (score 1):

An approach is to let a single thread find the next prime number in the sieve, and then let all threads mark the multiples concurently. Every thread will be assigned a different section of the array to avoid memory sharing as much as possible. So every thread needs to determine what range of multiples it will handle.

Answer (score 0):

First, should the parallelization affect the creation of the table, or
simply using it to determine whether a number is prime or not.  In a
real application, I'd do the first off line, so the table would appear
in the final C++ code as a statically initialized C style array.  So the
question of parallelization would be irrelevant.  And since nothing 
should be modified in the second, you can access from as many threads as
you want, without concern.

I suspect, however, that the purpose of the exercise is for you to use
multiple threads to construct the table.  (Otherwise, it doesn't make
sense.)  In this case: the table is constructed by a series of loops,
with steps 2, 3, 5...  Each of these loops can be executed in a separate
thread, but... some sort of synchronization will be needed for
concurrent accesses.  If you treat the table as a single object, with
just one lock, you'll end up either running the loops sequencially
(because you're acquiring the lock outside of the loop), or spending
more time acquiring and releasing the lock than doing any real work.
(Acquiring and releasing an uncontested lock can be very fast.  But not
as fast as just setting a `bool`.  And in this case, the lock is going
to be very, very contested, since all of the threads want it most of the
time.)  If you create a lock per `bool`, that's going to be an awful lot
of locks—it will probably take less time to construct the table in
a single thread than to create all of the mutexes.

Of course, in C++ (and perhaps in Java as well), you'll want to use a
bitmap, rather than one `bool` per entry; the larger the table, the
larger the maximum number you can handle.  (Something like `bool
sieve[INT_MAX];` is almost certain to fail; you might be able to get
away with `unsigned char sieve[INT_MAX / 8 + 1];`, however.)  In this
case, you'll need a mutex per element, not per entry (which would be a
single bit in the element).  Given that each mutex eats up some
resources as well, you probably want to divide the table into discrete
blocks, with a mutex per block, and use a nested loop:

```
int j = 0;
for ( int i = 0; i < numberOfBlocks; ++ i ) {
    scoped_lock( mutex_table[i] );
    while ( j < (i + 1) * bitsInBlock ) {
        //  ...
        j += step;
}
```

Once this is working, a bit of tuning will be necessary to determine the
optimal block size (but I would guess fairly big).

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher won't like this, but I guess there is a brutal approach which can be worth considering.

Just let every thread repeat

```
find the next prime in the sieve
mark all multiples of this prime
```

independently of all others and without any synchronization. Every thread stops when there it finds no more prime.

This is brutal because several threads may work on the same prime by accident, but the final sieve will be correct (all composites detected), and what you loose in terms of duplicate work could be regained by the absence of synchronization.